# Using Sql Unpivot

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this table and I need to convert it to the one below. I am guessing this can be done using unpivot but I cannot get about it. Can anyone help?

```
MAKER   LAPTOP  PC  PRINTER  

C       1       0     0  
B       1       1     0  
D       0       0     2  
E       0       3     1  
A       2       2     3  

MAKER   TYPE    Count

B       Printer  0  
C       PC       0  
C       Printer  0  
D       Laptop   0  
D       PC       0  
E       Laptop   0  
E       Printer  3  
A       Laptop   2  
A       PC       2  
A       Printer  3  
B       Laptop   1  
B       PC       1  
E       PC       3  
C       Laptop   1  
D       Printer  1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your table isn't too big, a `union all` is probably the easiest solution:

```
select maker, 'Laptop' as type, laptop as "count" from t union all
select maker, 'PC' as type, pc from t union all
select maker, 'Printer' as type, printer from t;
```